# How to pass email list to MailboxAddress from database Entity Framework in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to send bulk Emails by using MailKit.Net.Smtp, using MimeKit.

I get email lists and email body data like (feeamount and feetype), these two fields send to the same row email address.

Code to get list and data:

```
public IActionResult FeeNotification(int? id)
{
    var ids = _context.FeeEntry
                      .Where(i => i.FeeInfoID.Equals(id))
                      .Select(x => x.StudentID).ToList();

    var q = (from t in _context.FeeEntry
                               .Include(f => f.AddFeeInfo)
                               .Include(f => f.students)
             join std in _context.Students
                                 .Select(p => new StudentRegModel() { StudentID = p.StudentID }) on t.StudentID equals std.StudentID
             join fi in _context.FeeInfo.Select(p => new AddFeeInfo() { FeeInfoID = p.FeeInfoID }) on t.FeeInfoID equals fi.FeeInfoID
             where ids.Contains(std.StudentID)
             select t).ToList();

    return View(q);
}
```

I want to pass list of emailaddress to the

```
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(list of emailes)
```

[image: output view is browser this is just view if you have other way to complete this task please suggest me]

Send email code is this code send only one email, I want to send full list email that show above in in my code.

I know that foreach loop will work here but I do not know the proper way to use it.

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    var myvalues = (from values in _context.FeeInfo
                    where values.FeeInfoID == feeEntry.FeeInfoID
                    select values.FeeAmount).FirstOrDefault();

    client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
    client.Authenticate("emailaddress", "password");

    var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder
    {
        HtmlBody = $"<table style = 'border:2px solid blue' border='1'> <thead>  </thead>  <tr>" +
                   $"<th> </th><th>Name</th> <th>Submit Date </th>  <th>Fee Amount</th>  </tr> " +
                   $"<tbody> <tr> <th>1</th> <td>{std.Student.StdName}</td> <td> {feeEntry.FeeDeppositDate}</td> <td>{ViewData["FeeInfoID"]} </td><tr> </tbody> </table>  ",
        TextBody = "{formData.ID}\r\n{ formData.subject}\r\n{formData.body}\r\n{formData.Email}"
    };

    var message = new MimeMessage
    {
        Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody()
    };
    message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("No Reply OCMWP", "bs180201421@vu.edu.pk"));
    message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(std.Student.StdName, std.Student.StdEmailAddress));
    message.Subject = "Fee Submitted Information (OCMWP)";

    client.Send(message);
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

Comment: If you add multiple addresses to the `To` field, then every recipient can see who the email was sent to. I would recommend either adding recipients to the `BCC` or sending unique emails to each address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, `To` is a list, so if you have a list of students from your database you can do something like this to add them all to the same email:

```
foreach (Student student in students)
{
    message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(student.Name, student.EmailAddress));
}
```

Comment: dear i know that forecach loop work like this that show  in your answer but need full code to complete this action . i try my best but not complete it,s

Answer (score 1):

It works as below.

Sending bulk mail to database users with ASP.NET Core MVC and Entity Framework:

```
var q = (from t in _context.FeeEntry.Include(f => f.AddFeeInfo).Include(f => f.students)
         join std in _context.Students.Select(p=> new StudentRegModel() { StudentID = p.StudentID }) on t.StudentID equals std.StudentID
         join fi in _context.FeeInfo.Select(p => new AddFeeInfo() { FeeInfoID = p.FeeInfoID }) on t.FeeInfoID equals fi.FeeInfoID
         where ids.Contains(std.StudentID)
         select t).ToList();

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    foreach (FeeEntry student in q)
    {
        client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
        client.Authenticate("your email address", "password");

        var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder
        {
            HtmlBody = $"<table style = 'border:2px solid blue' border='1'> <thead>  </thead>  <tr>" +
                       $"<th> </th><th>Name</th> <th>Submit Date </th>  <th>Fee Amount</th>  </tr> " +
                       $"<tbody> <tr> <th>1</th> <td>{student.students.StdName}</td> <td> {student.AddFeeInfo.FeeAmount}</td> <td>{ViewData["FeeInfoID"]} </td><tr> </tbody> </table>  ",
            TextBody = "{formData.ID}\r\n{ formData.subject}\r\n{formData.body}\r\n{formData.Email}"
        };

        var message = new MimeMessage
        {
            Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody()
        };

        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("No Reply OCMWP", "mail address"));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(student.students.StdName, student.students.StdEmailAddress));
        message.Subject = "Fee Submited Information ( OCMWP)";

        client.Send(message);
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
}
```